# Errors while trying to make a Restful WebService with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, webservice-client

I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first) tutorial to create a CRUD RESTful WebService.

The tutorial for this type of WebService starts in paragraph 7. I create the Server and the Client.

The Server seems to work perfectly fine as i do what the author suggests to test it and everything works as expected.

**However** , the Client gives me a hard time. When i run it i always get this error:

```
201
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><todoes><todo><id>3</id><summary>Blabla</summary></todo><todo><description>Read complete http://www.vogella.com</description><id>2</id><summary>Do something</summary></todo><todo><description>Read http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html</description><id>1</id><summary>Learn REST</summary></todo></todoes>
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/CRUDserver/rest/todos returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
    at es.unican.cityInfo.client.Tester.main(Tester.java:34)
```

What exactly is the problem i cant understand ? Any ideas ?

The only assumption i can make , is based in this phrase of the author , in the beginning of building the client :

*`Create a new Java project called de.vogella.jersey.todo.client. Create a lib folder and place all jersey libs in this folder. Add the jars to the classpath of the project.`*

He says to place all *`jersey libs`* inside a folder. However what are these libs??? 
The only thing i have for the client are 2 jar files : `jersey-client.jar` and `jersey-core.jar` which i found on the site of jersey...

---

As suggested here is the log from the server , when i run the client :

```
Apr 26, 2013 5:46:19 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<es.unican.cityInfo.model.Todo>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
Apr 26, 2013 5:46:19 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

Apr 26, 2013 5:46:19 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<es.unican.cityInfo.model.Todo>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<es.unican.cityInfo.model.Todo>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Trying to create CRUD? :] (I've always loved that one.)

Comment: Yeap! But is giving me a hard time today :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting a 500 error, this means the code is erroring on the server side. You will have to look at the log on the server side to figure out what went wrong.

HTTP Status Codes are meant to give you information about the request.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

EDIT:

So it appears that your return type on the method being mapped to that HTTP request is JSON, but you have not registered a JSON message writer for Jersey to use.

Comment: Hmm i did notice on the code that the error was in the line with the Json message. But i just followed the tutorial :D How can i fix that?

Comment: Try adding the jersey-json.jar library

Comment: @DonP Google jersey-json.jar it is the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simples way is to use Jersey's POJO support feature. To enable it, add the JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING init parameter to the servlet configuration of your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                  ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
                  ...
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

You will probably need to add a couple of jar's in addition to the ones you already have. Check this link for a list of the dependencies:  https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1828

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer
>   for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type
>   java.util.List, and MIME media type
>   application/json was not found

I think your es.unican.cityInfo.model.Todo class is missing the following annotation  @XmlRootElement

i.e.

```
package de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement // never forget me
    // JAX-RS supports an automatic mapping from JAXB annotated class to XML and JSON
    // Isn't that cool?
    public class Todo {
      private String summary;
      private String description;
      public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
      }
      public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
      }
      public String getDescription() {
        return description;
      }
      public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
      }


    }
```