# Jersey client not working when run on Java Webstart

Tags: java, client, jersey, java-web-start

I have a Glassfish 3 server running with Jersey Rest webservices.

I have a swing app running as a client.

I can do everything I coded the app to do. (Add,delete,edit,view) Everything works as expected.

I want to distribute the swing app with Java Webstart.

In netbeans I run my application with webstart and get the following error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class       java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<za.co.lunginstitute.restbeans.Patient>, and MIME media  type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:535)
    at za.co.lunginstitute.restclient.BaseDAO.get(BaseDAO.java:37)
    at za.co.lunginstitute.restclient.PatientsDAO.findAll(PatientsDAO.java:39)
    at     za.co.lunginstitute.gregg.xrays.gui.models.PatientDataModel.loadAll(PatientDataModel.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at za.co.lunginstitute.gregg.xrays.workers.BackgroundRunner$BGRunner.doInBackground(BackgroundRunner.java:97)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I ran it under JavaWS 6 and 7. I used the JDK as well as the JRE.
Everything works as long as I stay away from webstart.

I tried running the app from the commandline as a normal java and then as javaws. Java works,but javaws gives me this error.

I did check the classpath, double and triple checked. All the libraries are present.

I used fiddler and everything works as expected. The connection is made, data is returned and then this error - only when using webstart.

Comment: Try looking at my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240637/errors-while-trying-to-make-a-restful-webservice-with-jersey/16240712#16240712

Comment: The server sends back the correct response and I can see the JSON in fiddler. I have all the Jersey libs on the classpath - the whole netbeans Jersey 1.13 library.

Comment: Did you even look at my answer on that page? You are missing `jersey-json` library most likely.

Comment: Yes, I did look. Made doubly sure jersey-json is in the classpath. And just checked again. It is there. Checked the javaws panel - it shows there. The app works when run with java, just not javaws. It loads and shows me my interface. I authenticate with glassfish and get a list of object which fail with the said error.

Answer (score 0):

Found "solution":

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
```

I did not have the last line in my code. After adding it I don't get the exception anymore.

Weird is that it worked  running app as java.exe, but not as javaws.exe.

Now I get this error futher on in the code:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of  java.util.Date from String value '1980-01-01 CAT': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse  date "1980-01-01 CAT": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source:   com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler$HttpClientResponseInputStream@140fbd9; line: 1,  column: 143] (through reference chain: za.co.lunginstitute.restbeans.Xray["xraydate"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.weirdStringException(StdDeserializationContext.java:243)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:553)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:28)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:19)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:194)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:565)
... 16 more
```

I do use this:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SimpleDateAdapter.class)
```

on the get method for the class. Again this works when running as java, not in javaws.

Am I missing something, some Jersey config settings.

Comment: Problem solved. Use: config.getClasses().add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);